# Problemas con jest SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, test, jest, ts

hola tengo un problema al correr npm test, y es que me tira este error de abajo ya probe instalando varias dependencias y todo lo que tiene que ver y configurando mi  jest config pero creo que el problema es que en mi llamada a la api uso axios

```
 

    **FAIL  src/__tests__/buttons/bookmarkBtn.test.tsx
      ● Test suite failed to run
    
        Jest encountered an unexpected token
    
        Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.  
    
        Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
    
        By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
    
        Here's what you can do:
         • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
         • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
         • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
         • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.  
         • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
    
        You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
        https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
        For information about custom transformations, see:
        https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
    
        Details:
    
        C:\Users\mayi\Desktop\week9-2\node_modules\axios\index.js:1
        ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                          ^^^^^^
    
        SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    
        > 1 | import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
            | ^
          2 |
          3 | async function http<T>(
          4 |   path: string,
```

pero igual me sigue dando error, reitero que estoy usando axios para llamada a mi API pero aun no estoy testeando esa parte pero aun asi sale ese error, ayuda este es mi package json tambien

````
   **{
      "name": "week8",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.23",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.31",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
        "sass": "^1.60.0",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --detectOpenHandles a --coverage",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.192",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.4",
        "babel-jest": "^29.5.0"
      },
      "jest": {
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "node_modules/(?!(axios)/)",  "node_modules/(?!(redux-persist)/)"
        ]
      }
    }
    ```**
````

Ya investigue bastante y aun no logro encontrar una solucion ayuda

Estoy usando react ts  ya probe con varias forma en configurar mi jest.config que esta asi

```
/**  @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */ module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!(axios)/)"],
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)",
  ],
  esModuleInterop: true,
};**
```

**